# Create SMTP Client and SMTP Server verify with ssl sertificates (cretaed on oepnssl)

Tags: java, email

I need a help to create the above:
safe transport of an email between two ends SMTP.I have to create 
SMTP Client SMTP Server and causality of the certificates to the various entities that 
need it.  Then I need to send the data from a  file xxxxxx.txt the other side.

I start with this code to create SMTP Client and Server, i am not sure if this is the correct code. (I need to use NetBeans) - ( I create also certificates with openssl )

// Client_Sock.java  code

```
package client_sock;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;

package client_sock;


public class Client_Sock {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    try
{
   Socket sock =new Socket ("locakhost",9999);
PrintStream pr = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
system.out.print("Ergasia 01 pes 620 20013:");
InputStreamReader rd = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
BufferedReader ed = new Bufferedreader(rd);

String temp = ed.readLine();

pr.println(temp);

BufferedReader gt = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
String tm = gt.readLine();
System.out.print(tm);


}
  catch (Exception ex)
{

        }
    }
}
```

---

//Server_Sock.java  code

```
package server_sock;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class Server_Sock {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

try
{
    ServerSocket ser = new ServerSocket (9999);
    Socket sock = ser.accept();

    BufferedReader ed =new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputsStream()));
    String tmp = ed.readLine();
    System.out.print("Irecieved:"+tmp);

    PrintStream pr = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
    String str = "The message delivered succesfully !!"
    pr.println(str);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you required to implement secure SMTP using plain sockets? Then you will need to read about SMTP protocol
2. If not you can look for SMTP packages

EDIT:
To find out about SMTP: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321
To transmit the message securely you can use one of the two approaches:

1. transmit the data over secure connection (i.e. negotiate secure connection with the server and then transmit the data in an ordinary fashion)
2. send encrypted message over unsecured connection

Comment: I am interesting for the 2nd option but can i continue this code or to create a new one?when you talk for SMTP packages you mean "smtp.pop3,e.t.c"?

Comment: Thank you Germann, I am new add at this site. i am trying to learn how is working.